# How to print debugging information on one/specific OpenAPI model?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

According to the [OpenAPI docs](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/debugging/) here is how one can print generator's models data:

```
$ java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate \
 -g typescript-fetch \
 -o out \
 -i api.yaml \
 -DdebugModels
```

which outputs 39000 lines and it's a little difficult to find a modele of one's interest.

How to output debug information on just one model?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to generate the debug log for just one model or operation.

As a workaround, you can draft a new spec that contains the model you want to debug.